# Springboot + Hibernate with ElasticSearch : Getting no results

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I want to enable search for a bunch of fields for one of my entities. Therefore, I added hibernate search to my spring boot project. When I load data into the database, I can see that Elasticsearch contains that data as expected in the index running

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty
```

I can run queries like

```
curl localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty&q=name:test
```

and receive the expected results.

I would like to give consumers of my API the option to run arbitrary queries like "name:test" against the index, so that

```
curl "localhost:8086/myentity/search/querySearch?query=name:test"
```

would return the same results as before in the direct query.

Here's what I am trying but whatever I do, I get 0 results:

```
public List<MyEntity> querySearch(String queryString) {
    QueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(ALL_FIELDS, new SimpleAnalyzer());
    queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(queryString));

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = 
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, MyEntity.class);

    return persistenceQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `QueryParser.escape(queryString)`, you remove the meaning of operators such as `:`. So if the user enters `name:test`, you will end up looking for documents that contain `name:test` (literally), instead of looking for documents whose `name` field contains `test`.

Remove that escape and everything should work as you want.

By the way, you're essentially using Lucene to parse a query that will then be sent to Elasticsearch. An easier solution would be to send the query to Elasticsearch directly, especially if you do not need to prevent users from accessing some fields.

```java
public List<Training> querySearch(String queryString) {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    QueryDescriptor query = ElasticsearchQueries.fromQueryString(queryString);

    javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query, Training.class);

    return persistenceQuery.getResultList();
}
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_queries

Comment: Thanks for that solution. That absolutely make sense! I am not using that way you suggested, because I would like it to work with Elasticsearch as well as local file index since I want to be able to run the software locally sometimes or want to avoid spinning up Elasticsearch to run tests etc.